# Wt c++ with Postgresql

Tags: c++, wt

I tried to connect with PostgreSQL database using wt c++ but shows the errors like

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'wtdbopostgresd.lib'`

How to build the library file using `cmake`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you build Wt yourself or are you using the binary releases? I don't think the binary releases include the postgres backend for now.

If you have built Wt yourself, set POSTGRES_PREFIX to the path where your postgres was installed, so that it finds the necessary header files and libraries.